# get live TV Video Stream (pixel)

Tags: java, android, streaming, google-tv, television

is there a way to get the live tv stream, to analysize it for example on pixel level.

My Goal is to check the live tv stream (for example with java) if for example the broadcast station logo is visible or not.

Is there a chance to get this stream over google tv?
Is there a chance to get this stream over a dvb-t card or dvb-s receiver for the notebook?

any further information required?

Answer (score 4):

No. Google TV needs to comply with [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdcp) - so they can't let you touch the TV stream.

Answer (score 1):

2014 LG EzySign TV supports display of the HDMI input "TV program" scaled to be displayed in a template developed using an Adobe AIR desktop application which allows the template to be populated by users who want to display other media on the same screen as the TV program.

2014 Samsung Smart Sign TV does the same thing only better.

Most if not all TV manufacturers have modified their TV devices to support the metaphor we call Picture-in-Picture (PIP) in hardware and in software.

SO IT IS NOT TRUE AND IT WAS NEVER TRUE TO SAY...
"No. Google TV needs to comply with HDCP - so they can't let you touch the TV stream."

Yes, Google and all of us need to comply with HDCP but HDCP compliance in hardware and HDCP compliance in software are two different things when it comes to claims of copyright violations hence, that earlier statement is a specious argument that cannot lead to a sound conclusion.

HDCP as such has no means to disallow the use and display of PIP which many TV devices have lawfully supported in hardware for decades and only then because nobody had the software to do PIP in software. Furthermore, current TV development platforms prove the assertion. Simply determining which screen resolution the HDCP content will be displayed in is not a copyright violation or PIP would not exist whether PIP is done in hardware or whether PIP is done in software.

I have been challenging lawyers for ~10 years to prove the FUD that persists but none have ever been able to prove their assertions; what they are doing is trying to hinder innovation.

It also -appears- to be the fact that Android L now supports doing PIP in software however exactly how and such is still vague. These are the facts as I've been able to ascertain them to be which is why I am here tonight...

..to see if anybody else is already trying to learn how to programmatically manage PIP using the Android L OS